# Nexus 4 does not turn it on and blinking red notification light only

Tags: nexus-4, power-on, notification-led

This morning, my Nexus 4 (Android 5.0.1) had some issues about Google apps crashing. I decided to do factory reset, so I went to Settings and apply factory reset, it was showing power turn-off, then it has not been started again. I tried to plug charger and everything but nothing is worked out.

Now, when I plug it to wall USB charger or laptop USB charger, I can't see any charging icon. I tried to hold down <kbd>power</kbd> + <kbd>volume down</kbd> buttons, but nothing happen. However, when I hold <kbd>power</kbd> + <kbd>volume down</kbd> buttons and plug it to any charger, it shows red notification light which blinks for 10 seconds. Releasing the buttons made the light go off.

Tried below solutions, but nothing worked for me till now:

1. Put it charging more than 2 hours.
2. Checked solutions from [Red notification light on Nexus 4, won't power on, device unresponsive](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/39548/red-notification-light-on-nexus-4-wont-power-on-device-unresponsive) too, but no success.
3. Checked this Deep Hibernate solution from [here](http://www.guplum.com/nexus-4-not-charging-and-turning-on-and-died-suddenly-hibernation-issue/)
4. Also tried XDA developers [solution](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=43291951&postcount=27)

Any other possible solutions?

Comment: Try to take out the battery and put it back in later. Or try with someone else's Nexus 4 battery.

Comment: Tried to remove battery and put it back. It does not work. Same thing as like previous.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem once a week and have a little different solution (workaround):

1. Unplug the phone from the charger
2. Press and hold the <kbd>volume down</kbd> button plus <kbd>power</kbd> button for 15 seconds
3. Plug it into the wall-charger (while still holding both buttons!)
   -> the red light should start to blink.
4. After 4-5 blinks release the buttons
5. Wait some seconds and then press the <kbd>power</kbd> button and it should boot

Maybe this workaround will help you.

Answer (score 2):

I had luck holding the power and volume down button for 10 seconds, then plugging in the usb charger. I was presented with the technical boot screen which gave me a few options (start, recovery mode, etc) - I just selected start and it began to power on as normal. Now charging with the white icon from 0% charge.