# Nexus 4 Red Notification light with full battery

Tags: battery, nexus-4

I have a problem with my Nexus 4.

About once in a week it goes in the "deep hibernation mode" and shows this behavior: [Red notification light on Nexus 4, won't power on, device unresponsive](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/39548/red-notification-light-on-nexus-4-wont-power-on-device-unresponsive)

My problem is, that this seems not to be a battery problem. Because this happens with 100% of battery, sometimes even when it is plugged to the power supply.

It is very annoying for me, because when this happens I always have to do this procedure to "solve" it:

1. Unplug the phone from the charger)
2. Press and hold the volume DOWN button plus POWER Button for 15 seconds
3. Plug it into the wall-charger (while still holding both Buttons) -> the red light should start to blink.
4. After 4-5 blinks release the buttons
5. Wait some seconds and then press the Power Button and it should boot

After that procedure it works without any problems for a week or so, and after the reboot I often have 70-100% battery.

Because the battery works then for a week I don't think it happens because of battery drain. Now has anyone another idea, why this is happening?

Comment: [Couple of fixes here](https://lists.launchpad.net/ubuntu-phone/msg03731.html) may help

Comment: I get it out of the hibernation mode without any problems with the above-noted procedure every time.
My problem is, that my nexus4 enters the deep hibernation mode randomly a couple of times per week after going into standby. Even when it is plugged in or has over 70% of battery. 
This is very annoying for me since I always must have a charger nearby to get it out of that mode.
Additional information I forgot: I have Stock ROM without any modification or root or something else, but it is encrypted.

Comment: I can't help beyond that. Sorry. I just posted the answer and deleted it seeing that your problem was not fixed fully

Comment: Although I doubt it would help, do a full factory reset... Then replace the battery, I know it seems like the battery is fine since it reports a good charge on reboot, but the electronics in the battery pack is probably failing. I had a similar condition occur from time to time on my N4, replaced the battery with a new OEM one and the problem never recurred.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I already replaced the battery with a new one and/or did a Factory Reset, but it didn't solve the problem.
I examined the problem in more detail and it _only_ enters the deep hibernation mode when going into stand-by (via timeout or via pressing power button) _and_  not being connected to the charger (pc or wall).
So for me it seems to be a hardware issue with standby-mode?
Because if I  don't enter standby mode it works perfectly and the battery lasts as long as before the problem.